# Flag your own question

Tags: support, questions, flagging

It's funny that you can not only answer your own question, but also *flag* it.
Why one would do this? Why this possibility exists at all? Is it a joke?

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: why is it a joke? There are many reasons why you'd want to flag it - flamewar in comments, rollback wars, ask a Mod to delete it, migrate it elsewhere, all answers shilling for a service etc etc

Comment: What OS has tooltips that look like buttons?!

Comment: @DanielBeck it's Windows 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've flagged some of my questions in the past for moderator attention when there's various issues like Sathya mentioned. Flagging a question doesn't necessarily mean that there's something inherently wrong with the question itself; you can use it to bring attention to anything going on in the "thread" that is otherwise bad.

Now of course, if people say that my question needs clarification or other improvement, I'll just edit it.

If a question has answers, you can't delete it, so if I agree that it's off-topic or not a good fit for SU after the fact, I can flag it to be closed, or vote to close it once I have enough rep.

Comment: Before I was able to do it myself, I would often have to flag my own questions to request that they be protected if they were getting too many off-topic answers.